# Как работает сборщик мусора?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

Где-то слышал, что если у нас есть большой объект и мы хотим заново его инициализировать

```
BigObject bigObject = new BigObject();
// do something
bigObject = new BigObject();
```

То лучше сначала приравнять его к null и только после этого инициализировать заново

```
BigObject bigObject = new BigObject();
// do something
bigObject = null;
bigObject = new BigObject();
```

Якобы тогда сборщик мусора (garbage collector) будет работать эффективнее. Правда ли это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Есть один случай, когда использование принудительного обнуления не только полезно, но и фактически обязательно, это когда ссылка на объект обладает большей областью действия чем та, в которой она фактически используется или считается действительной в спецификации программы. Это включает такие случаи, как использование вместо локальной переменной статического поля или поля экземпляра объекта для хранения ссылки на временный буффер или использование массива для хранения ссылок, которые могут оставаться доступными для среды выполнения, но не для неявной семантики программы." (с)
Я бы советовала Вам ознакомиться с историей развития технологии [утилизации памяти](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp10283/index.html)  и после этого закрепить [Сборка мусора и производительность](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp01274/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ: и да, и нет. Если при создании объекта запустится сборка мусора, то если не обнулить ссылку, то окажется, что старая ссылка ещё живая, потому что присвоение произойдёт после того, как объект будет создан. Так что, теоретически, установив ссылку в null мы снизим вероятность падения по OOM. С другой стороны, подобная ситуация скорее всего означает, что что-то было не продумано в вашем приложении. И более того, лишнее онуление ссылок - пустая трата ресурсов. Не говоря уже о том, что установка переменной в null не будет видима на других процессорах, так что сборщик может всё равно не увидеть изменения. Так что на самом деле, делать это бессмысленно. И это точно не заставит сборщик работать эффективнее.

PS: так что на самом деле, манипуляции со ссылка не по боку, но толку от них весьма мало.

Answer (score 2):

На сайте IBM было сказано, что обнуление ссылок только путает сборщик.
Сборка мусора - разовый процесс, запускаемый вирт машиной и собирающий все недоступные в момент запуска ссылки (так гласит стандарт). Любые пляски с указателями ему побоку.

Answer (score 0):

Если конкретно отвечать на твой вопрос - нет, это не правда.

Присваивать null целесообразно только в том случае, если между `= null;` и следующим `= new BigObject();` выполняются какие-либо длительные действия, по длительности превышающие паузы между сборками (при стандартной стратегии они будут не меньше минуты, а в большинстве случаев больше, особенно если куча свободна.

Т.е. когда время жизни переменной сильно больше требуемого времени жизни самого объекта.

Кстати к IBM это не имеет никакого отношения, все современные JVM так или иначе почти одинаково чистят кучу.